# Solution to duplicate Site or Copy a site collection granularly

Tags: site-template, template, provisioning, copy-and-paste, duplicate

I'm a sharepoint admin and I'm receiving request everyday to duplicate a site or site collection. Site templates has limitations so I really want to have something to help me. I want to be able to select Subsite that I want to keep within the site collection I want to copy and select the permissions as well. More granular than just a template or a simple copy of a site collection

Answer (score 0):

I used the shareGate for migration as well as for the site collection moving stuff.

We have requirements all the time moving sites between farm, copying the sites, moving contents etc.

Sharegate fulfill our requirements, you can try it as they offer trial for 15 days

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Actually, I saw Sharegate, looks really good. But I don't need to do migration. But more to use a tool on a daily basis that will duplicate a site collection that we already have and select the permissions I want to keep along with the sites (subsites). More granular. Not just a copy as is, but that I can choose within. Any recommendation?

Comment: That tool is not only for migration but also for day to day activities as you mentioned. We are using this for daily work,moreover it is cheap as compare to others

Comment: Can I contact you directly as I have few questions for you? You can also email me at michaelgreenwood692@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Any of the migration tools will do just fine. The main ones in the market are:

- Metalogix Content Matrix
- AvePoint DocAve
- Dell Migration Manager for SharePoint
- ShareGate

I believe all of them have free versions of their tools which you can try.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I'm so confuse on which one to use. But I don't need to do migration. More to use a tool on a daily basis that will duplicate a site collection that we already have and select the permissions I want to keep along with the sites (subsites). Like templates. More granular. Not just a copy as is, but that I can choose within. Any recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a granular backup of the pages library (site collection source) in Central Administration, and restore the pages library in site collection destination if you don't have any other pages you need to save in that library.

Or you can backup the entire site collection using Backup-SPSite powershell script and run Restore-SPSite to another web application (with another content database) in the same farm.

One of the options could be to save a site template. Then deploy it in a site collection and to create new sites from it.

Few more migration tools out there, you could try like:

[Lepide SharePoint Migration Tool](https://www.lepide.com/lepidemigratordocuments/sharepoint-to-office-365-migration.html)

[MigrationWiz SharePoint Migration](https://www.bittitan.com/products/migrationwiz/sharepoint-migration/)

Hope this helps!